# Faceting variable must have at least one value

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create a dashboard, but I keep coming across the error, faceting variable must have at least one value. I am new to shiny, and I think the issue is with the filter in the reactive.

I am trying to be able to filter dates for the selected athlete for the two variable that I selected through facet_wrap.

structure(list(Name = c("Player_1", "Player_1", "Player_1", "Player_1",
"Player_1", "Player_1", "Player_1", "Player_1", "Player_1", "Player_1",
"Player_1", "Player_1", "Player_1", "Player_1", "Player_1", "Player_2",
"Player_2", "Player_2", "Player_2", "Player_2", "Player_2", "Player_2",
"Player_2", "Player_2", "Player_2", "Player_2", "Player_2", "Player_2",
"Player_2", "Player_2", "Player_2", "Player_2"), Date = c("10/25/22",
"10/20/22", "10/18/22", "10/11/22", "10/4/22", "9/29/22", "9/22/22",
"9/20/22", "9/15/22", "9/13/22", "9/8/22", "9/6/22", "9/1/22",
"8/30/22", "8/25/22", "10/25/22", "10/20/22", "10/18/22", "10/11/22",
"10/6/22", "10/4/22", "9/29/22", "9/27/22", "9/22/22", "9/20/22",
"9/15/22", "9/13/22", "9/8/22", "9/6/22", "9/1/22", "8/30/22",
"8/25/22"), `Eccentric Duration [ms]` = c(672, 712, 625, 659,
673, 745, 563, 763, 915, 581, 726, 593, 691, 661, 588, 423, 406,
481, 424, 397, 396, 455, 409, 431, 469, 440, 435, 450, 431, 471,
466, 448), `RSI-modified [m/s]` = c(0.28, 0.3, 0.29, 0.28, 0.29,
0.27, 0.34, 0.26, 0.24, 0.33, 0.27, 0.31, 0.28, 0.27, 0.33, 0.46,
0.46, 0.38, 0.47, 0.48, 0.49, 0.42, 0.48, 0.4, 0.37, 0.38, 0.4,
0.41, 0.39, 0.36, 0.36, 0.43)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -32L))

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
library(DT)
library(viridis)
theme_set(theme_classic())


### Load in the data 

force_data <- read_csv('metrics.csv') %>% 
drop_na()
#### Change the date

force_data$date_formatted <- as.Date(force_data$Date, 
tryFormats = c("%m/%d/%y"))

readiness <- force_data %>% 
select(Name, date_formatted, `Eccentric Duration [ms]`, `RSI- 
modified [m/s]`) %>% 
pivot_longer(cols = 3:4,
           names_to = "Names",
           values_to = "Values")


# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- navbarPage("Force Plate Dashboard",

    tabPanel("Readiness",
     selectInput("Athlete",
                label = h3("Select Athlete"),
                choices = unique(readiness$Name),
                selected = 1),
    dateRangeInput("Date",
                 label = h3("Select Date:"),
                 start = "2020-08-25",
                 end = NULL),

    mainPanel(plotlyOutput("Plot1"))

))


 server <- function(input, output, session) {

dat <- reactive({
  
  d <- readiness %>% 
    group_by(Name) %>% 
    filter(date_formatted %in% input$Date,
           Name == input$Athlete)
  
  d
})


output$Plot1 <- renderPlotly({
  
   d <- dat()
  
   readiness_plot <- print(
     ggplotly(
    ggplot(d, aes(date_formatted, Values)) + 
      geom_line(color = "blue") + 
      geom_point() + 
      labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) + 
      scale_color_viridis_d() + 
      theme_classic() + 
      theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
            axis.text.x = element_text(size = 9, angle = 45, 
      vjust = 1, hjust = 1, color = "black"),
            axis.text.y = element_text(size = 10, color = 
      "black"),
            strip.text.x = element_text(size = 12, face = 
      "bold"),
            panel.spacing = unit(1, "lines"),
            legend.position = "bottom",
            legend.title = element_blank()) + 
      facet_wrap(~Names, scales = "free")))
   
     print(readiness_plot)
    
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Your guess is probably right. The error you get most likely indicates that your data has zero rows after filtering. But without [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data it's hard to check that. One issue might be that `input$Date` is a dateRange, i.e. a vector of length 2. Hence, using `%in%` you filter for the start and end date. The way I use a dateRange would be to filter for `date_formatted >= input$Date[1] & date_formatted <= input$Date[2]`.

Comment: Thank you, I have updated my post with data!

Comment: That's an improvement. But images of data/code are not really useful. If you want to post your data type `dput(NAME_OF_DATASET)` into the console and copy the output starting with `structure(....` into your post.  If your dataset has a lot of observations you could do e.g. `dput(head(NAME_OF_DATASET, 20))` for the first 20 rows of data.